# Relationship between taxonomy field and other fields within a content type (recipe example)

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I'm looking to implement a recipe content type, in which the ingredients are chosen from a taxonomy list using the reference field; and the amount of each ingredient varies and added manually per recipe.

How do I create a realtionship between the taxonomy field and the amount field? Does drupal implicitly assume a relationship according to the order of input? Or do I need to use a different module for that? (Paragraphs module?)

To clarify my need: imagine a view that queries and displays the number of eggs used in each recipe.

I'm using drupal 10 (and have preference for relying on drupal core functionality only, if at all humanly possible in this case. )

Thanks in advance for any ideas how to design this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I create a realtionship between the taxonomy field and the amount field? Does drupal implicitly assume a relationship according to the order of input?

The order of the items in separate fields does provide a (weak) relationship, which you *could* exploit manually in preprocess functions/templates - but it would mean you have to maintain the two lists separately, which will get more awkward as a recipe gets more complex. Imagine having to manage those lists for a Beef Wellington!

You also may want to add another dimension in the future (e.g. "Prep details" for each ingredient), and then you'll have 3 lists to manage.

You've already mentioned the easiest solution, which is [Paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs). It was built for pretty much exactly the kind of use case you've described, is very mature, and has plenty of complementary modules to get additional functionality quickly (like [Paragraphs table](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs_table)). Plus the UI for managing fields is identical to core, so very little learning curve. For basic to mid-level requirements it's an out-of-the box, no-code solution, and works great.

Another option is to create your own [custom field type](https://www.drupal.org/docs/creating-custom-modules/creating-custom-field-types-widgets-and-formatters/create-a-custom-field-type), field widget(s), formatter(s), etc. Unless you need the (probably only very small) performance improvement this method provides, or need something specific that Paragraphs doesn't offer, it's probably overkill for what you're describing.

Comment: An example would be the [Ingridient](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/recipe/-/blob/8.x-2.x/modules/ingredient/src/Plugin/Field/FieldType/IngredientItem.php?ref_type=heads) field type of the module [Recipe](https://www.drupal.org/project/recipe).

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! All make sense.